# Django Auth Views Password Reset URL

Tags: django, authentication, view

I using Django Password reset in my project. I have and namespace called "users" and inside this app (yes, it an app too), I build my urls. But when I use Django Password Reset of `auth_views`, they send a url like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/auth/reset/NA/4ou-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
```

But my reset url is like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/users/reset/NA/4ou-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
```

How I change URL of Django Auth Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a url pattern a set a view to that url.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset, password_reset_confirm
urlpatterns = [
    url('/users/reset/NA/$', password_reset, name='password-reset')
    url('/users/reset/NA/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                         password_reset_confirm, name='pass-reset-confirm')
]
```

This would override the existing urls.
You can read more about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset)